# Probability n people will meet, finding CDF and PMF.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $n$ people should meet each other on interval $[0, 1]$. Suppose $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are time of arriving each of $n$ people. For all $i\in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ $X_i$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. Define $X:=min\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$ and $Y:=max\{X_1, ..., X_n\}$. Find $F_{X, Y}(x, y)$ and $f_{x, y}(X, Y)$.

We can find either $F_{X, Y}$ or $f_{X, Y}$.
For example suppose $x < y$, then $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = \mathbb{P}(X = x, Y = y) = \mathbb{P}(min\{X_1, ..., X_n\} = x, max\{X_1, ..., X_n\} = y) = \mathbb{P}((X_1, ..., X_n)\in [x, y]) = (y - x)^{n}$.

It seems to be incorrect, and is it possible to find CDF firstly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{P}((X_1, ..., X_n)\in [x, y]) = (y - x)^{n}$ is a probability so unlikely to be the density function.  It is instead $\mathbb{P}( X \gt x \cap Y \le y)$ when $0 \le x \le y \le 1$, and note that when $x=0$ it is equal to $\mathbb{P}(Y \le y) = y^n$

So for the cumulative distribution function $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ you want to find $\mathbb{P}( X \le x \cap Y \le y)$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(Y \le y)-\mathbb{P}( X \gt x \cap Y \le y)$,  which for $0 \le x \le y \le 1$ is then $$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = y^n-(y - x)^{n}$$ and the double derivative with $n \ge 2$ then gives $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = n(n-1)(y - x)^{n-2}$$

The density is zero elsewhere, but for completeness you should state the CDF:

- $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ when $x \lt 0$ or $y \lt 0$
- $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=y^n$ when $0 \le y \le 1$ and $y \lt x$
- $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=1-(1-x)^n$ when $0 \le x \le 1$ and $y \gt 1$
- $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=1$ when $x \gt 1$ and $y \gt 1$

There is a slight issue when $n=1$ as $Y=X$ so $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is not particularly meaningful as a density function.  When $0 \le x \le 1$ you have $F_{X}(x)=x$ and $f_X(x)=1$

Answer (score 0):

The joint distribution can be obtained as follows: $F(x,y)=P(X\le X\ and\ Y\le y)=P(Y\le y)-P(X\gt x\ and\ Y\le y)$.
Using the independence of  the $X_i$, we have $P(Y\le  y)=y^n$, while $P(X\gt x\ and\ Y\lt y)=(y-x)^n$.
Thus $F(x,y)=y^n-(y-x)^n$.